# Is ~49 °C normal for motherboard idle temperature?

Tags: motherboard, temperature, overheating

My motherboard model name is Gigabyte GA-78LMT-S2PT. It's normal idle temperature shows 49 °C. Ambient room temp is 30 °C. Idle CPU ([AMD FX-6100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_FX_microprocessors#.22Zambezi.22_.2832_nm_SOI.29)) temperature is 27 °C.

Is 50 °C too hot (for my motherboard)?

Comment: Check with your motherboard manufacturer's website or check the manual which comes with it. Ideally it should warn you if the tempreture raises above stipulated temp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not too hot. 50 degrees C is pretty normal and safe temperature for electronics. However I would be worried about the CPU temperature. It seems to me that you are having a problem with temperature sensor, or its calibration. From numbers you have provided, your CPU temperature is lower than your ambient room temperature. This is not possible for air cooled systems. So I would assume the reported value is wrong. Also, It does not seem logical that your CPU temperature is lower then MB temperature. CPU's are normally over 80 degrees C.

Comment: can you suggest me a good temperature monitoring software/utility application ? normally i use speccy and  core temp and both shows CPU temp is lower than motherboard .

Comment: The point I was trying to make in my post is that the problem you have is not in the software you use. You might have a faulty sensor that is not reporting the correct temperature. Software just displays it to you.

Comment: And why are you worried about the temperature in the firs place? Do you experience any problems with it? Does you machine shutdown unexpectedly due to overheating. Does the smoke come out of it? If now, then your bet bet is just to leave it as it is ans stop worrying.

Comment: nopes..it's working perfectly . bt i had some bad experiences with my previous asus motherboard..thats why am so curious about the temperature..anyways thanx for your help..:)